# How to play hd, 1080p prime content in brave or firefox in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, video-streaming, drm

I have enabled the all the three plugins in firefox as drm, open264 and shockwave flash, but I cannot play hd, fullhd in amazon prime. For the brave browser, I couldn't find any plugin options. I have tried installing ubuntu restricted extras.

Comment: You also need the google widevine plugin.  In firefox, you should be notified of this the first time you try to play DRM content.  Perhaps you dismissed it?

Comment: no I switched it to always active

Comment: and the remaining 2 plugins also